# Does sidekiq use any dependent application to initialise its processes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I am trying to understand how sidekiq works.

Does sidekiq load all the dependencies via the rails initializer by loading all the gems or does it use some sort of an applications server while spawning its workers?

Comment: It loads rails environment like a normal rails app, yes. Then instead of listening to web requests, it spawns workers.

Comment: So it eats as much memory as Rail application does, maybe more if your Rails server is threaded.

Comment: May be this helps you(not sure why they have removed this): https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Internals/45bb65591f9fbfc553013a72ce0739c4e9049b83

Comment: It was removed because it is not true for >= 4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bundler loads the gems that Sidekiq depends on.  Rails and/or your initializer load your application code.  Sidekiq will automatically boot Rails so it can load the app code if it detects Rails, otherwise you have to use `-r` to tell Sidekiq the file to require to boot your app.

See the code in sidekiq/cli.rb for the exact details.